# How to import Vensim model to Anylogic PLE?

Tags: anylogic, parsing-error, vensim

I have encountered "parsing error! com.anylogic.ui.bad: encountered " ","","" at column X, row Y, was expecting: ..."
The Vensim model is in MDL format and consists of three simple formulas, however, the importer doesn't work. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: never seen this error.. can you share your vensim file?

Comment: It's a simple test model with just two variables, 1 constant and 1 auxiliary. None of the equations, names, and views have space included in naming. Constant variable equals to 1, Auxilary is constant*5. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug

I just tested models with Vensim 7 and no problem to import, but with vensim 8 it's impossible to import models, and I get your same error.

I will report this problem to AnyLogic.

Response from AnyLogic:

> Our converter was written several years ago, and we do not maintain
>   compatibility with newer versions of Vensim.They have updated file
>   format, and we need to research it, and update our converter. This is
>   not a taks with high priority. Vensim 8 support will be added in next
>   versions (8.8 or later).